# Sympy underscores in MatrixSymbol change appearance in pretty print

Tags: python, sympy

If I generate a symbolic matrix using an underscore in the variable name:

```
import sympy as sp
v_fluid = sp.MatrixSymbol('v_fluid',1,3)
V_fluid = sp.diag(*v_fluid )
sp.pprint(V_fluid )
```

I obtain:

```
⎡v_fluid_00      0           0     ⎤
⎢                                  ⎥
⎢    0       v_fluid_01      0     ⎥
⎢                                  ⎥
⎣    0           0       v_fluid_02⎦
```

But if I do not use the underscore:

```
v_fluid = sp.MatrixSymbol('vfluid',1,3)
V_fluid = sp.diag(*v_fluid )
sp.pprint(V_fluid )
```

The output in the IPython viewer looks different:

```
⎡vfluid₀₀     0         0    ⎤
⎢                            ⎥
⎢   0      vfluid₀₁     0    ⎥
⎢                            ⎥
⎣   0         0      vfluid₀₂⎦
```

Calculations do not seem to change. Is this behaviour just a graphic issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not just a graphic issue. Recall that the first argument you pass to `sp.MatrixSymbol` is a SymPy symbol. In your first case, you are passing it

```
>>> v_fluid = sp.MatrixSymbol('v_fluid',1,3)
>>> v_fluid
```

[image]

whereas in your second case,

```
>>> v_fluid = sp.MatrixSymbol('vfluid',1,3)
>>> v_fluid
```

[image]

This SymPy symbol is handled by LaTex when pretty printing. In the first case, your underscore is handled as a LaTex special character, and you subscript both `fluid` as well as your digits

```
v_{fluid}_{0, 0}
```

Which results in

[image]

In your second case, LaTex is not confused by any underscore, and ***only*** subscripts your digits

```
vfluid_{0, 0}
```

resulting in notation like this!

[image]

Then if you `pprint`, the double subscripting is just handled literally, which results in the underscores in your matrix, whereas a single underscore following `vfluid` actually subscripts your digits.